# Google Fit step counter history returns nothing

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-fit

I want to write an app which displays all steps done this week by asking the Google Fit API. Unfortunately my History API call always returns empty DataSets.

For debugging I am using a Nexus 9 Tablet with Google Fit installed. I added steps manually in the Google Fit app.

This is my code to get the steps

OnCreate:

```
...
mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
...
```

Function to get steps

```
private void showSteps() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();

    DataReadResult dataReadResult = Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mApiClient, readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);


    if (dataReadResult.getBuckets().size() > 0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Number of returned buckets of DataSets is: "
                + dataReadResult.getBuckets().size());
        for (Bucket bucket : dataReadResult.getBuckets()) {
            List<DataSet> dataSets = bucket.getDataSets();
            for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Data returned for Data type: " + dataSet.getDataType().getName());
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

                for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Data point:");
                    Log.i(TAG, "\tType: " + dp.getDataType().getName());
                    Log.i(TAG, "\tStart: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
                    Log.i(TAG, "\tEnd: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
                    for(Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "\tField: " + field.getName() +
                                " Value: " + dp.getValue(field));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (dataReadResult.getDataSets().size() > 0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Number of returned DataSets is: "
                + dataReadResult.getDataSets().size());
        for (DataSet dataSet : dataReadResult.getDataSets()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Data returned for Data type: " + dataSet.getDataType().getName());
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

            for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Data point:");
                Log.i(TAG, "\tType: " + dp.getDataType().getName());
                Log.i(TAG, "\tStart: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
                Log.i(TAG, "\tEnd: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
                for (Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "\tField: " + field.getName() +
                            " Value: " + dp.getValue(field));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I receive buckets and they have dataSets but they never have any DataPoints. The code just finishes without errors. The ApiClient returns that it is indeed connected to Google Fit.

Why does the History API not return my steps I added to the Google Fit app?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out the code was fine. I noticed that I was logged into a different google account on my tablet when I added the steps. Obviously the account has to be the same.

Comment: hey buddy, do you need to have google fit app installed on your device to get the history data or it just works without it

Comment: Thanks, and one more thing regarding the data that Api gives us . Does it give the data which was written (inserted) in the api by client or it gives the actual count walked by the user in case we don't insert anything into Fit api manually.

Comment: Thats something I haven't really figured out myself yet... At first I thought it works like Apple's Health API where steps etc are always counted by iOS and written in the Health API. When I started playing around with Google Fit on the other hand I got some strange data... still testing. If you find anything new let me know^^

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `.enableServerQueries()` to your Data read request. It fetches data from Google fit server when not available locally.